# error C2143 VC++12

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++-cli, header-files

i'm getting a C2143 error in a very simple header. can you help me find what's wrong?

```
#ifndef GLOB_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOB_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

 extern string *name, *surname, *dob, *hospNo, *addr, *sex, *email, *phone, *nhs, *allerg, *indic, *notes;
 extern int leftc, rightc, middlec;
 extern string ks;

#endif
```

if you need further explanation in anything... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `using namespace std;`after the include of the string header :)

Comment: It's not good to add a 'using' statement to another header - it forces the whole namespace into the scope of any code that #include's that header.

Comment: @roger_rowland im totally agree with you, my intention was providing quick solution to the issue without diving too much to C++ best known methods :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "std" namespace - but rather than adding a "using" clause to your header file (which is bad practice), qualify your names like this:

```
#ifndef GLOB_H_INCLUDED
#define GLOB_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

extern std::string *name, *surname, *dob, *hospNo, *addr, *sex, *email, *phone, *nhs, *allerg, *indic, *notes;
extern int leftc, rightc, middlec;
extern std::string ks;

#endif
```